# How to use Pattern attribute for a manual string that i want in my email validation

Tags: html

I want to validate a particular string in my users email
like I want email which is containing 'stack' string.
ex. user.stack@gmail.com

I wrote following code but its not working

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" pattern=".+.stack" required />
```

Please suggest me a correct pattern syntax

Comment: Your pattern `.+.stack` means that your e-mail should contain any char one or several times, followed by any char once and then followed by "stack". If you wanted to say that it must contain ".stack" then you should escape the dot and it would become `.+\.stack`. But this would not work because "  .stack@test.com" would match as the *any char* could be a space. I'm not sure the browser trims the spaces. And what about "james@bond.stack" ? is this valid for you? We need more details in your question.

Comment: Why the PHP tag? Please only add tags that are relevant to your issue.

Comment: I'm only wanted to emails for signup which are containing .stack in their email like name.stack@anyemail.com

Answer (score 0):

currect attribute for cotaining specific string as fallows

```
pattern=".+stack@gmail.com"
```

Full code as fallows

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" pattern=".+stack@gmail.com" required />
```

Comment: I thought you where looking for a username finishing with ".stack" for any domain name.
I used the "almost 99% correct" regex from http://emailregex.com and changed it so that you only accept usernames finishing with ".stack": https://regex101.com/r/TU69LA/2